# JavaFX 2.x : Extend vertical line on sub pane(s)

Tags: javafx-2, bar-chart, linechart

This code plots a LineChart upper pane and a bar Chart in lower pane.

There is also a vertical line plotted left/right X move with pointer.

I would like to extend this vertical line also to the lower subpane, such as the attached picture

[image]

How to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Here is the code

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineBuilder;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class XyChartInSplitOnlyCursor extends Application {
SplitPane               splitPane1 = null; 
BorderPane              pane1; 
BorderPane              pane2; 
Line                    LV;
XYChart.Series          series1 = new XYChart.Series(); 
XYChart.Series          series2 = new XYChart.Series(); 

@Override 
public void start(Stage stage) {      
stage.setTitle("Lines plot"); 

final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(1, 12, 1); 
final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0.53000, 0.53910, 0.0005); 

xAxis.setAnimated(false);
xAxis.setScaleX(0);
yAxis.setAnimated(false);

yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis) { 

    @Override 
    public String toString(Number object) { 
        return String.format("%7.5f", object); 
    } 
}); 

final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart1 = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis); 

lineChart1.setCreateSymbols(false); 
lineChart1.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false); 
lineChart1.setAnimated(false); 
lineChart1.setLegendVisible(false);

series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 0.53185)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 0.532235)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 0.53234)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 0.538765)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 0.53442)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 0.534658)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 0.53023)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 0.53001)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 0.53589)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 0.53476)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 0.530123)); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 0.531035)); 

lineChart1.getData().addAll(series1);         

pane1 = new BorderPane(); 
pane1.setCenter(lineChart1); 

splitPane1 = new SplitPane();                                
splitPane1.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
splitPane1.getItems().addAll(pane1);
splitPane1.setDividerPosition(0, 1);

final CategoryAxis xAxis2 = new CategoryAxis();
final NumberAxis   yAxis2 = new NumberAxis();

yAxis2.setTickUnit(1);
yAxis2.setPrefWidth(35);
yAxis2.setMinorTickCount(10);

yAxis2.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis2){
        @Override
        public String toString(Number object){
            String label;
            label = String.format("%7.2f", object.floatValue());
            return label;
        }
});

final BarChart<String, Number>BarChart = new BarChart<String, Number>(xAxis2, yAxis2);

BarChart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
BarChart.setLegendVisible(false);
BarChart.setAnimated(false);

XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();

series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 1));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", 3));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", 1.5));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Apr", 3));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("May", 4.5));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jun", 5));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jul", 4));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Aug", 8));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Sep", 16.5));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Oct", 13.9));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Nov", 17));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Dec", 20));

BarChart.getData().addAll(series2);

pane2 = new BorderPane(); 
pane2.setCenter(BarChart);

Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         double percSplit;

         splitPane1.getItems().addAll(pane2);

        ObservableList<SplitPane.Divider> splitDiv =  splitPane1.getDividers();

        percSplit = 1/(double)(splitDiv.size()+1);
        for (int i = 0; i< splitDiv.size(); i++) {                        
            splitPane1.setDividerPosition(i, percSplit);
            percSplit += 1/(double)(splitDiv.size()+1);
            }
     }
 });

Scene scene = new Scene(splitPane1, 800, 600); 
stage.setScene(scene);         

pane1.setOnMouseMoved(mouseHandler); 

LV=LineBuilder.create()
        .startX(0)
        .startY(0)
        .endX(10)
        .endY(.535)
        .strokeWidth(1)
        .stroke(Color.BLACK)
        .build();
pane1.getChildren().add(LV);

stage.show();
} 
EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { 

@Override 
public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED) { 
        LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = (LineChart<Number, Number>) pane1.getCenter(); 

        NumberAxis yAxis = (NumberAxis) lineChart.getYAxis(); 
        NumberAxis xAxis = (NumberAxis) lineChart.getXAxis(); 

        double newXlower=xAxis.getLowerBound(), newXupper=xAxis.getUpperBound(); 

        double xAxisShift = getSceneShift(xAxis);
        double yAxisShift = getSceneShift(yAxis);

        if(mouseEvent.getX()>xAxisShift && mouseEvent.getX()<xAxisShift+xAxis.getWidth()){

        LV.setStartX(mouseEvent.getX());
        LV.setStartY(yAxisShift);
        LV.setEndX(mouseEvent.getX());
        LV.setEndY(yAxisShift+yAxis.getHeight());
        }
    } 
}
}; 
private static double getSceneShift(Node node) { 
double shift = 0; 
do {  
    shift += node.getLayoutX();  
    node = node.getParent(); 
} while (node != null); 
return shift; 
}   
public static void main(String[] args) { 
launch(args);  
} 
}
```

Edit: added picture after jewelsea modify

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add the line to the pane in the SplitPane, instead create a Group which layers the line over the SplitPane.

```
Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(splitPane1, line), 800, 600);
```

If you want the Scene resizable, you can use a StackPane instead of a Group and bind the lines length to the scene height to get it to fill the Scene.

Here is a sample of applying using a StackPane and binding to extend the line in a resizable scene.  Note, similarly to the originally posted code, the code is explicitly coded to only move the line when the mouse is inside the plot area of the top chart.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineBuilder;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class XyChartInSplitOnlyCursor extends Application {
  SplitPane splitPane1 = null;
  BorderPane pane1;
  BorderPane pane2;
  Line LV1, LV2;
  XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
  XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Lines plot");

    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(1, 12, 1);
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0.53000, 0.53910, 0.0005);

    xAxis.setAnimated(false);
    xAxis.setScaleX(0);
    yAxis.setAnimated(false);

    yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis) {
      @Override
      public String toString(Number object) {
        return String.format("%7.5f", object);
      }
    });

    final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart1 = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

    lineChart1.setCreateSymbols(false);
    lineChart1.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
    lineChart1.setAnimated(false);
    lineChart1.setLegendVisible(false);

    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 0.53185));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 0.532235));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 0.53234));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 0.538765));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 0.53442));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 0.534658));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 0.53023));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 0.53001));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 0.53589));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 0.53476));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 0.530123));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 0.531035));

    lineChart1.getData().addAll(series1);

    pane1 = new BorderPane();
    pane1.setCenter(lineChart1);

    splitPane1 = new SplitPane();
    splitPane1.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
    splitPane1.getItems().addAll(pane1);
    splitPane1.setDividerPosition(0, 1);

    final CategoryAxis xAxis2 = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis2 = new NumberAxis();

    yAxis2.setTickUnit(1);
    yAxis2.setPrefWidth(35);
    yAxis2.setMinorTickCount(10);

    yAxis2.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis2) {
      @Override
      public String toString(Number object) {
        String label;
        label = String.format("%7.2f", object.floatValue());
        return label;
      }
    });

    final BarChart<String, Number> BarChart = new BarChart<String, Number>(xAxis2, yAxis2);

    BarChart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
    BarChart.setLegendVisible(false);
    BarChart.setAnimated(false);

    XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();

    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 1));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", 3));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", 1.5));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Apr", 3));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("May", 4.5));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jun", 5));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jul", 4));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Aug", 8));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Sep", 16.5));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Oct", 13.9));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Nov", 17));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Dec", 20));

    BarChart.getData().addAll(series2);

    pane2 = new BorderPane();
    pane2.setCenter(BarChart);

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        double percSplit;

        splitPane1.getItems().addAll(pane2);

        ObservableList<SplitPane.Divider> splitDiv = splitPane1.getDividers();

        percSplit = 1 / (double) (splitDiv.size() + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < splitDiv.size(); i++) {
          splitPane1.setDividerPosition(i, percSplit);
          percSplit += 1 / (double) (splitDiv.size() + 1);
        }
      }
    });

    LV1 = LineBuilder.create()
            .strokeWidth(2)
            .stroke(Color.FORESTGREEN)
            .build();

    StackPane stack = new StackPane();
    Pane glassPane = new Pane();
    glassPane.getChildren().add(LV1);
    glassPane.minWidthProperty().bind(splitPane1.widthProperty());
    glassPane.minHeightProperty().bind(splitPane1.heightProperty());
    glassPane.setMouseTransparent(true);
    stack.getChildren().addAll(splitPane1, glassPane);
    Scene scene = new Scene(stack, 800, 600);
    LV1.endYProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    pane1.setOnMouseMoved(mouseHandler);

    stage.show();
  }

  EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
      XYChart<Number, Number> chart1 = (XYChart<Number, Number>) pane1.getCenter();
      plotLine(chart1, LV1, mouseEvent.getX() + 1);
    }
  };

  private void plotLine(XYChart<Number, Number> chart, Line line, double x) {
    Axis xAxis = chart.getXAxis(), yAxis = chart.getYAxis();
    final double min = getSceneShift(xAxis);
    final double max = min + xAxis.getWidth();
    boolean setCrosshair = false;
    if (x > min && x < min + xAxis.getWidth()) {
      LV1.setStartX(x); LV1.setEndX(x);
      setCrosshair = true;
    } else if (x <= min){
      LV1.setStartX(min); LV1.setEndX(min);
    } else if (x >= max){
      LV1.setStartX(max); LV1.setEndX(max);
    }
    if (setCrosshair) {
      chart.setCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR);
    } else {
      chart.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
    }
  }

  private static double getSceneShift(Node node) {
    double shift = 0;
    do {
      shift += node.getLayoutX();
      node = node.getParent();
    } while (node != null);
    return shift;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

[image: Sample program output]

Comment: Hi jewelsea, I have updated my question with a picture after your suggestion

Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(splitPane1, LV), 800, 600);

but as you can see I didn't get the expected result.

I am missing something or, as an alternative, is there a way to use bind, and if so, how to?

Comment: To use just a Group you need also to do extra work to extend the line over both graphs.  I updated the answer to provide a sample with StackPane + Bind because your original sample seems to be resizable anyway.

Comment: I have now a similar question but related to horizontal line

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616843/javafx-2-x-how-to-extend-horizontal-line-on-subpanes